# Android ASAN llvm-symbolizer cpp function

Tags: android, c++, makefile, android-ndk, address-sanitizer

So I found this blog that explains how you would call the llvm-symbolizer binary for understanding which lines of code cause violations (buffer overflows, use-after-free, etc.):

https://www.nrbtech.io/blog/2022/3/22/using-address-sanitizer-asan-to-debug-c-memory-issues-in-android-applications

My question is if there is a library, from the NDK, that I can include which would allow me to print out similar information that llvm-smybolizer does. I would like this since it would be easier to have it print **immediately** vs me writing a script that would filter the logcat logs and call llvm-smybolizer. If I need to include anything extra flags to enable this, within my makefile, please let me know. Thanks for the help!

Also - I know there is ndk-stack, which can do something similar to what I am looking for, but I would really prefer to call a library function that can produce the same information.

From an example: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/639 - I would like to print out something like this, but also tell me the EXACT location that the error was caused by a given violation.

Also, in valgrind you can pass in --track-origins=yes and --leak-check=full to find line numbers, is there something similar to ASAN debugging?